# How can I use several xml filter for one xml message

Tags: xml, xpath, logstash

I have to parse an XML document (received as a rabbitmq message) but I want to get some more info according some filters.
Here the xml part of my logstash

```
if ([message] =~ /^</) {
  xml {
    ...
    xpath => [
      "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/IDENT/NO_EMIARTE/text()", "NO_EMIARTE",
      "name(/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/*[not(self::METADATA)])","MESSAGE_TYPE",
      "name(/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/*)","RECOMMENDATIONS",
      "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/APIOS_EXPORT/METADATA/CODE_OFFRE_WEB/text()","OFFRE_WEB"
    ]
    target => "xml"
  }
  alter {
    condrewrite => [
      "MESSAGE_TYPE","","EDITO"         
    ]
    condrewriteother => [
      "RECOMMENDATIONS","RECOMMENDATIONS","MESSAGE_TYPE","RECOMMENDATIONS"
    ]
    condrewriteother => [
      "RECOMMENDATIONS","SCHEDULE","MESSAGE_TYPE","SCHEDULE"
    ]
    remove_field => [ "RECOMMENDATIONS" ]
  }
  if [MESSAGE_TYPE]=="SCHEDULE" {        
    xml{
      source => "message"
      store_xml => false
      xpath => [            
        "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/SCHEDULE/DAY/@DATE","DAY"
      ]
      target => "xml"          
    }
  }
}
```

So here if I have a SCHEDULE MESSAGE_TYPE I would like to add a filter to get the DAY but it seems quite complex to do so. I have the feeling that MESSAGE_TYPE is not available in my if statement

It's all good until `if [MESSAGE_TYPE]=="SCHEDULE" {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't know why it wasn't working but the code below works well

```
...
remove_field => [ "RECOMMENDATIONS" ]
      }
      if [MESSAGE_TYPE]=="SCHEDULE" {
        xml{
          source => "message"
          store_xml => false
          xpath => [
            "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/SCHEDULE/DAY/@DATE","DAY",
            "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/SCHEDULE/DAY/ELEMENT/NO_EMIARTE/text()","NO_EMIARTE",
            "/APIOS_MOM_EVENT/DATA/SCHEDULE/DAY/ELEMENT/ID_PROG/text()","ID_PROG"
          ]
          target => "xml"
        }
      }
```

The new fields are now well fulfilled in ES.